# Dúvidas sobre o pretérito perfeito e imperfeito

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, gramática

Eu tinha/tive muito dinheiro

Para mim me parece a mesma coisa: ele teve e não tem mais. Mas a definição do P.I. é de "fatos passados dando ideia de continuidade e permanência" então ele tinha e continua tendo dinheiro?

Answer (score 5):

Nenhum dos dois tempos indica que ele ainda tem dinheiro.

Em geral:

- o *pretérito perfeito* sugere uma ação **pontual** no passado, e
- o *pretérito imperfeito* sugere fato habitual, ou uma ação que se estendeu, que teve uma **duração** finita.

Então:
"Eu tive dinheiro [em algum *momento* do passado].", e
"Eu tinha dinheiro [em algum *período* do passado]."

Note que não é a duração absoluta que determina o tempo verbal, mas sim o contexto, especialmente a relação com outros tempos verbais. Por exemplo:

"Eu fiz as compras ontem."
"Enquanto eu fazia as compras o telefone tocou."

As duas frases se referem ao mesmo fato passado (fazer as compras) que, portanto, teve a mesma duração (digamos, meia hora), mas o primeiro exemplo pede o perfeito ("o fato aconteceu") enquanto o segundo pede o imperfeito ("enquanto aquilo acontecia, outra coisa aconteceu").

Claro que também é possível ter dois eventos pontuais no passado: "Quando *li* o relatório, *descobri* o problema."; ou dois extensos: "Enquanto *lia* o relatório, *bebericava* seu suco.".

E há casos em que os dois tempos são possíveis:
"Na faculdade eu *li* muito pouco." (um fato) e "Na faculdade eu *lia* muito pouco." (um hábito).

É fácil achar mais exemplos e explicações na rede, por exemplo no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/preterito-perfeito-vs-imperfeito/4842) ou no site de [Português do UOL](http://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/preterito-perfeito-imperfeito-marcas-distintivas.html).